# Skip the first N lines and print the rest of the file, given there is a file corruption in the middle of the file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, tail, ioerror

I have a large text file that is corrupted in the middle When I attempt to read this file, say find the number of lines using awk:

```
person@terminal> awk 'END{print NR}' file.txt
awk: (FILENAME=file.txt FNR=300) fatal: error reading input file `file.txt': Input/output error
```

So I have thought about using tail command to print all that comes after this corrupted line, and join the output with all that comes before it. The tail command works fine by default, as it starts reading the file from the end of this file, so it can print the very end of this file without problems. But the problem is that, I do not know how many lines this file has. So if I try to skip all the lines before the corruption point using tail, I get:

```
person@terminal> tail -n +301 file.txt > after_error.txt
tail: error reading `file.txt': Input/output error
```

Which means that although tail can read the file starting from, of course, the end of a file, it still reads from the start of the file if I tell it to skip the first N lines.

My question is, how would I print all lines after my corruption point? I am also more than happy to know if there are other ways to salvage this file.

Comment: `dd` with `bs=1` and `skip=OFFSET` might work better for you

Comment: `dd` with `skip` is about the only reasonable way to avoid corruption. You can also `hexdump` or `od` the file to determine the offset where the corruption ends.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
strings file.txt
```

or

```
cp file.txt /otherPartition/file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for offering these potential solutions, however neither of these two works for my file, which is corrupted in the middle, for string command it prints all lines before the error point then stops, for cp command, it prints I/O error when reaching the corrupted point. Could you think of other ways? Thanks!

Comment: I never needed `fchk`, don;t know if that helps.